# what is use of get_HZ()

Tags: programming, system

please tell me what is the use of get_HZ() system call. Any link for its documentation??
I tried to search for this in google but could not get the usage of this function

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Probably from the old days, when computer clocks ran from the power supply frequency (50Hz in some parts of the world, 60Hz elsewhere). The value is needed when converting from # of clock interrupts to actual, real wallclock seconds.